# 404Error When I open /admin/appname/ on Apahce(mod_wsgi)

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

When I open /admin on my local domain use development server,It all work.
When I move this project to Apache,Other pages work normal,But When I open admin site,click 'All' or 'Change',I get a 404 Error

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:  http://localdomain/admin/article/article/
>
> Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> 1. ^admin/ ^$
> 2. ^admin/ ^logout/$
> 3. ^admin/ ^password_change/$
> 4. ^admin/ ^password_change/done/$
> 5. ^admin/ ^jsi18n/$
> 6. ^admin/ ^r/(?P\d+)/(?P.+)/$
> 7. ^admin/ ^(?P\w+)/$
>
> The current URL, admin/article/article/, didn't match any of these.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get this url `admin/article/article/`? This pattern should have been defined in your `urls.py` file right?

Comment: Thanks MovieYoda,In my urls.py I only defined (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), it's normal on development server,but 404Error on Apache.

Comment: I get this url [admin/article/article] when I click 'edit' a app which name is 'article' in admin site.Should I defined (r'^admin/appname', include(admin.site.urls)), in urls.py?